# Php colour coding groups in table rows

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I am having difficult colouring a table based on a group associated with a value in a key.  Extract below.

At the moment the first row of the 'group' shows red, and then the subsequent members of the group are amber, and so on....  I know why that is happening, but for the life on me I cant figure out how to get the loop in the right order to, have all `$var['tagid']` that are the same, to be red and then the next different 'tagid' to be the amber, then back to red, etc etc.

```
$groupid = null;
$output = '<table class="table">';

foreach($data as $key => $var)
{
  echo $var['tagid'];

  if($var['tagid'] != $groupid)
  {
    $output .= '<tr class=table-danger>';

    foreach($var as $k => $v)
    {
      $output .= '<td style="5%">' . $v . '</td>';
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $output .= '<tr class=table-warning>';

    foreach($var as $k => $v)
    {
      $output .= '<td style="5%">' . $v . '</td>';
    }
  }

  $groupid = $var['tagid'];
}
```

Here is an example array, but I dont know how to display it as a table here....

```
array(42) 
{ [0]=> array(16) { ["tagid"]=> string(38) "S_04CF22A8-31B4-4581-BC57-A3BD288D25C7" ["tagtime"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 20:18:18" ["lat"]=> string(11) "52.10000000" ["long"]=> string(11) "-3.20000000" ["moonRise"]=> string(9) "Not Today" ["moonSet"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 15:41:54" ["moonPhase"]=> float(0.814284) ["windDirection"]=> string(7) "100°" ["windSpeed"]=> string(7) "13.1mph" ["temp"]=> string(10) "11.85°C" ["weatherCondition"]=> string(6) "Clouds" ["airPressure"]=> float(1011) ["precipitation"]=> string(3) "0mm" } 
[1]=> array(16) { ["tagid"]=> string(38) "S_04CF22A8-31B4-4581-BC57-A3BD288D25C7" ["tagtime"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 20:18:42" ["lat"]=> string(11) "52.10000000" ["long"]=> string(11) "-3.20000000" ["moonRise"]=> string(9) "Not Today" ["moonSet"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 15:41:54" ["moonPhase"]=> float(0.814292) ["windDirection"]=> string(7) "100°" ["windSpeed"]=> string(7) "13.1mph" ["temp"]=> string(10) "11.85°C" ["weatherCondition"]=> string(6) "Clouds" ["airPressure"]=> float(1011) ["precipitation"]=> string(3) "0mm" } 
[2]=> array(16) { ["tagid"]=> string(38) "S_04CF22A8-31B4-4581-BC57-A3BD288D25C7" ["tagtime"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 20:18:51" ["lat"]=> string(11) "52.10000000" ["long"]=> string(11) "-3.20000000" ["moonRise"]=> string(9) "Not Today" ["moonSet"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 15:41:54" ["moonPhase"]=> float(0.814295) ["windDirection"]=> string(7) "100°" ["windSpeed"]=> string(7) "13.1mph" ["temp"]=> string(10) "11.85°C" ["weatherCondition"]=> string(6) "Clouds" ["airPressure"]=> float(1011) ["precipitation"]=> string(3) "0mm" } 
[3]=> array(16) { ["tagid"]=> string(38) "S_0DB2D804-A2F7-4CDA-B744-C7AD9926E999" ["tagtime"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 19:47:18" ["lat"]=> string(11) "52.10000000" ["long"]=> string(11) "-3.20000000" ["moonRise"]=> string(9) "Not Today" ["moonSet"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 15:41:54" ["moonPhase"]=> float(0.81363) ["windDirection"]=> string(7) "100°" ["windSpeed"]=> string(7) "13.1mph" ["temp"]=> string(10) "11.85°C" ["weatherCondition"]=> string(6) "Clouds" ["airPressure"]=> float(1011) ["precipitation"]=> string(3) "0mm" } 
[4]=> array(16) { ["tagid"]=> string(38) "S_0DB2D804-A2F7-4CDA-B744-C7AD9926E999" ["tagtime"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 20:07:46" ["lat"]=> string(11) "52.10000000" ["long"]=> string(11) "-3.20000000" ["moonRise"]=> string(9) "Not Today" ["moonSet"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 15:41:54" ["moonPhase"]=> float(0.814062) ["windDirection"]=> string(7) "100°" ["windSpeed"]=> string(7) "13.1mph" ["temp"]=> string(10) "11.85°C" ["weatherCondition"]=> string(6) "Clouds" ["airPressure"]=> float(1011) ["precipitation"]=> string(3) "0mm" } 
[5]=> array(16) { ["tagid"]=> string(38) "S_0DB2D804-A2F7-4CDA-B744-C7AD9926E999" ["tagtime"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 20:10:55" ["lat"]=> string(11) "52.10000000" ["long"]=> string(11) "-3.20000000" ["moonRise"]=> string(9) "Not Today" ["moonSet"]=> string(19) "2022-10-19 15:41:54" ["moonPhase"]=> float(0.814128) ["windDirection"]=> string(7) "100°" ["windSpeed"]=> string(7) "13.1mph" ["temp"]=> string(10) "11.85°C" ["weatherCondition"]=> string(6) "Clouds" ["airPressure"]=> float(1011) ["precipitation"]=> string(3) "0mm" } 
[6]=> array(16) { ["tagid"]=> string(38) "S_158E8F79-77F0-4485-B0AE-B75635F4EAA2" ["tagtime"]=> string(19) "2022-10-20 14:57:08" ["lat"]=> string(11) "50.45082112" ["long"]=> string(11) "-4.06133970" ["moonRise"]=> string(19) "2022-10-20 00:33:06" ["moonSet"]=> string(19) "2022-10-20 15:56:11" ["moonPhase"]=> float(0.838046) ["windDirection"]=> string(7) "151°" ["windSpeed"]=> string(4) "2mph" ["temp"]=> string(10) "14.85°C" ["weatherCondition"]=> string(6) "Clouds" ["airPressure"]=> float(1011) ["precipitation"]=> string(3) "0mm" }
```

So the table is changing line colour, but only for the first NEW tagid, and then the rest are amber.

Comment: Please give more details and some example data.

Comment: Sample input data and expected output would make this a lot clearer.

Comment: Adding random output between the table and tr tags (as you are doing with `echo $var['tagid'];`), is going to invalidate your table structure. If removing that doesn't fix your problem, then provide a proper [mre] of the issue including a sample data set, please.

Comment: Where is the part where you are _closing_ your table row elements again ...?

Comment: What is `style="5%"` supposed to do?

Comment: You shouldn't be repeating so much text in the if branches.  If only the class changes,  then just write a condition for that attribute value.  This question Needs Debugging Details.